# What Can I Do When the Message "miss client id" Is Displayed During AppGallery Connect Service Integration?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, huawei-push-notification

When I referred to official documentation of AppGallery Connect for APM integration and packaged and run the app, an error message was displayed in the run log:

```
I/com.huawei.agc.apms: failed to fetch remote config: client token request miss client id, please check whether the 'agconnect-services.json' is configured correctly.
```

The log is as follows.
[Please see the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbmF7.png)

According to the error message, I checked the agconnect-services.json file of my demo project. It was found that the client ID in the JSON file was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the AppGallery Connect plug-in to the **app-level** build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect.apms'
```

For details about how to integrate the AppGallery Connect plug-in, please refer to the following:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started#h2-1587477308727?ha_source=hms1